# Getting started on declaring Variables for it to be used in macro formula / formatting

Tags: excel, vba

There will only be one Currency Code variation per Excel Sheet.

From what I understand, I will need to declare an Integer / String and depending on the Currency Code it will change as such.
I'm not sure how to get started on declaring it.

This is only what I understand so far.

```
IF Table1[CurrencyCode] = USD or AUD or SGD or ...
THEN
x = 2 
y = "#,##0.00"

ELSE
x = 0
y = "#,##0"
```

Formula in question that will use the Variable

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=ROUND((R[-1]C[3]*RC[-1]),x)"
Selection.NumberFormat = "y"
```

Comment: `Dim x as long, y as string` .. how would you `round(number, 00)`  though?

Comment: sorry about that, typo an extra 0

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of errors in your code related to string concatenation and variables use

Could you try this lines instead?

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=ROUND((R[-1]C[3]*RC[-1])," & x & ")"
Selection.NumberFormat = y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `"x"` (in quotes), you are telling VBA you want a literal string containing a single character `"x"`.

If you remove the quotes, you are telling VBA you want whatever the current value of your variable `x` is.

Have left some comments in the code below, which can hopefully help/explain further.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FormatSomeCurrency()

    ' Declare your variables to use them later
    Dim roundingPrecision As Long
    Dim numberFormatToApply As String

    ' How are you going to get the currency code from the/each sheet?
    ' This is a task/question in itself and is not clear from your question.
    ' This code below is basically getting the value from "CurrencyCode" column
    ' of the table "Table1"
    ' The (1) at the end means we only want the first value (in the column).
    ' Change this as necessary.
    Dim currencyCodeFromSheet As String
    currencyCodeFromSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1[CurrencyCode]")(1)

    Dim specialCurrencies As Variant ' These currencies are "special" in the context of this procedure in that they require specific treatment
    specialCurrencies = Array("USD", "AUD", "SGD") ' You could also (instead) get this array from a worksheet instead of hard coding it here.

    ' This next line is pretty much equivalent to:
    '       IF Table1[CurrencyCode] = USD or AUD or SGD or ...
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(currencyCodeFromSheet, specialCurrencies, 0)) Then
        roundingPrecision = 2
        numberFormatToApply = "#,##0.00"
    Else
        roundingPrecision = 0
        numberFormatToApply = "#,##0"
    End If

    ' If you're expecting ActiveCell to be cell A1 (for example), then in your code say Range("A1") instead of ActiveCell
    ' Better yet, specify the workbook and worksheet that cell A1 belongs to. The more specific you are, the better.
    With ActiveCell
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND((R[-1]C[3]*RC[-1])," & roundingPrecision & ")"
        .NumberFormat = numberFormatToApply
    End With

End Sub
```

---

**Refactored into argument-accepting procedure**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FormatSomeCurrencyCell(ByRef cellToFormat As Range)

    Dim currencyCodeFromSheet As String
    currencyCodeFromSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1[CurrencyCode]")(1)

    Dim specialCurrencies As Variant ' Require specific treatment
    specialCurrencies = Array("USD", "AUD", "SGD")

    Dim roundingPrecision As Long
    Dim numberFormatToApply As String

    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(currencyCodeFromSheet, specialCurrencies, 0)) Then
        roundingPrecision = 2
        numberFormatToApply = "#,##0.00"
    Else
        roundingPrecision = 0
        numberFormatToApply = "#,##0"
    End If

    With cellToFormat
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND((R[-1]C[3]*RC[-1])," & roundingPrecision & ")"
        .NumberFormat = numberFormatToApply
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub InvokeProcedure() ' <-- Call this whatever you want.

    ' Continuing on from the initial example
    FormatSomeCurrencyCell ActiveCell

    ' You could also call it as below (for example):
    FormatSomeCurrencyCell ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10")

    ' Or on multiple cells at once:
    FormatSomeCurrencyCell ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10:B20")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed explanation, that helps alot.  Yeah the data will only be in sheet1 and will only contain table1.  
As for the currency array, the data I receive will only contain one currency at a time so theres not much choice other than having to hardcode it there.  
Do I need to paste the whole code everytime I needed it? or I can use roundingPrecision and numberFormatToApply on formulas that are further down

Comment: @David, have edited my answer. If you want to format some cell(s), just call the `FormatSomeCurrencyCell` procedure (rather than copy-pasting the original code throughout your procedure). See `InvokeProcedure` to see how to call `FormatSomeCurrencyCell` procedure and pass it an argument. You can probably get rid of the `FormatSomeCurrency` procedure (as it has been replaced by `FormatSomeCurrencyCell` procedure), but I'll leave it in my answer as the comments may help you/others.